# VBA Class Method Chaining

Tags: class, vba, methods

I'm looking for a way to 'chain class methods', for example the Range object can do things like "Range.Borders.Color", I guess that the Borders part is it's own class which is being accessed by the Range class but I have no idea how to implement something similar with my own classes - Nor do I even know what this is called and after hours of searching I think I might slowly be un-learning VBA.

Can anybody either a) Provide code which I could look at to replicate or b)  Tell me what this is called and maybe even nudge me in a helpful direction?

As I know asking for code without providing any makes me look like a dick, consider the following pseudo-code. I know it's horrific but it might help me make any sense:

main ------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
Dim obj as class1
set obj = new class1

obj.Target = Range("A1:B5")
obj.Borders.Add

'A1:B5 put into modRange then given borders
```

class1 ------------------------------------------------------------------------

```
Private modRange as range

Public Property Let Target(newTarget as Range)
  set modRange = newTarget
End Property

Public Property Borders()
    Public Sub Add()
        'Code to add borders to modRange
    End Sub 
    Public Sub Remove()
        'Code to remove borders from modRange
    End Sub 
End Property
```

I know this is not how the actual code would look. but as I don't know the syntax this is the closest thing I can imagine. I guess the real thing would have class1 linking to other class modules. Maybe.

As a side note. If I did have a class called "Borders" (I probably wont) as part of this class 1 object, would it conflict with the Borders portion of the Range object as well as it has a similar name? Or will the Private scope save the day?

(The .Borders.Add/Remove is a bit ridiculous to have as a class I know, I'm really only after the syntax - Honest)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To have complex properties of an object, you need to create a new class and then create an instance of that class in the parent class. So if you want to have something like `Class1.Borders.Add()`, you'd first have to create a new `CBorders` class (I used to prepend `C` to my class names in VB6 / VBA to avoid name collisions). Something like:

```
'- in class CBorder
Private m_lColor As Long

Public Property Get Color() As Long
    Color = m_lColor
End Property

Public Property Let Color(ByVal lNewColor As Long)
    m_lColor = lNewColor
End Property

Public Sub Reset()
    m_lColor = 0
End Sub

...
```

Then inside Class1, you'd have something like this:

```
Private m_oBorder As CBorder

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    ...
    Set m_oBorder = New CBorder
    ...
End Sub

Public Property Get Border() As CBorder
    Set Border = m_oBorder
End Property

...
```

Then you can do this:

```
Dim obj As Class1
Set obj = New Class1

obj.Borders.Color = ...
...
```

Notice how the `Borders` property of `Class1` is accessed as a member of the `obj` instance and then how the `Color` property of the `CBorder` class is used. Creating these values as properties is what lets you chain these calls together.

You'd need error checking and validation code as well - I left those out to keep the example short.

Comment: Beautiful. I was almost there I just didn't know to set the getter as an object. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 4):

Another solution for this is to just return Me to make it chainable.

## class module: CChaining

Using Functions for Target and Borders returning Me to enable chaining. Using Subs for Add and Remove to "finish" the chain.

```
Private modRange As Range, modRangeBorders As Object

Public Function Target(rng As Range)
    Set modRange = rng
    Set Target = Me
End Function

Public Function Borders()
    Set modRangeBorders = modRange.Borders
    Set Borders = Me
End Function

Public Sub Add()
    modRangeBorders.LineStyle = xlContinuous
End Sub

Public Sub Remove()
    modRangeBorders.LineStyle = xlNone
End Sub
```

## Testing the class in a module

```
Sub testing()
    Dim obj As New CChaining
    obj.Target(Range("A1:B5")).Borders.Add
    'now the target and property (Borders) is set and you could do this
    'obj.Remove
End Sub
```

Pretty nice ... hmm, with this it would be possible to build a library like in other languages (javascript > jQuery) to make using Excel VBA much easier.