# VBA chaining custom classes properties

Tags: vba, class

I'm playing around (learning) with VBA custom classes and I cannot figure out one thing, or I do not even know if it is possible to do (inheritance limitation in VBA)

I gathered something about chaining from this post
[VBA Class Method Chaining](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17764917/vba-class-method-chaining)

Within the example in link above you can write

```
obj.Borders.Color '-> this will return long type of color value
```

but you cannot use `obj.Borders` because `Borders` is declared as derived class, declared within main class `obj` and color is property of this derived class.

What I'm trying to figure out is how to chain properties/methods in custom classes

Something like

```
dim pvt as pivottable

set pvt = ....

pvt.pivotcache '-> method returns pivotcache object
pvt.pivotcache.memoryused '-> returns property of pivotcache object
```

any simple example how to do this with custom classes. I seem not to be able to wrap my head around this.

Thank you in advance for any example

Comment: what in your link is quite self explaining : have you tried it? In any case you need to post your entire code attempt to make your question more likely to get answers

Comment: Ok, I'm figuring it out slowly.

Comment: I'm just learning so no complex code, trying to get hold of for me new concept. Example what I wanted to do was object.property(string).property(string). Now that I'm thinking about this I cannot find any such example in VBA. all the time you go object.object.property. And with examples in that link it is the same.

Comment: a `String` typed property is not an `Object` so cannot have a property itself. You'd better depict your scenario

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When a class has a property of a type which has another properties then you can use them like a box which contains another box which contains another box which contains ... and so on. When the property doesn't contain any properties then it is `atomic` and contains just a value like e.g. `string` or `long`. Example

> Top level class named `Pivottable`. Contains reference to object of type `Pivotcache`

```
Private m_pivotcache As Pivotcache

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    Set m_pivotcache = New Pivotcache
End Sub

Public Property Get Pivotcache() As Pivotcache
    Set Pivotcache = m_pivotcache
End Property

Public Property Let Pivotcache(ByVal vNewPivotcache As Pivotcache)
    Set m_pivotcache = vNewPivotcache
End Property
```

> Another class named `Pivotcache`. It has atomic property `MemoryUsed` of type `Long`.

```
Private m_memoryused As Long

Private Sub Class_Initialize()
    m_memoryused = 0
End Sub

Public Property Get MemoryUsed() As Long
    MemoryUsed = m_memoryused
End Property

Public Property Let MemoryUsed(ByVal vNewMemoryUsed As Long)
    m_memoryused = vNewMemoryUsed
End Property
```

> Test in standard module

```
Sub test()
    Dim pvt As Pivottable
    Set pvt = New Pivottable
    pvt.Pivotcache.MemoryUsed = 123456789
    Debug.Print pvt.Pivotcache.MemoryUsed
End Sub
```